# Oracle - Transpose (Pivot)

Tags: oracle, pivot, transpose

I have a table like this:

| ID | C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

and I want to get to this:

| ID | Category | Category_Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C1 | 1 |
| 1 | C2 | 0 |
| 1 | C3 | 1 |
| 2 | C1 | 0 |
| 2 | C2 | 1 |
| 2 | C3 | 0 |
| 3 | C1 | 1 |
| 3 | C2 | 0 |
| 3 | C3 | 1 |

How can I do it? (I will add that I need It dynamic, because today I have 40 columns next week I can have 50 columns)

Thank you!

Comment: How do you define which columns should be pivoted and which are not? Are these `Cn` real column names or there may be other columns (for example, some date, description of the ID and others).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another dynamic option is to Use [UNPIVOT](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-unpivot/) -

```
SELECT * FROM DATA
UNPIVOT (
         Category_Value FOR Category IN (C1 AS 'C1', C2 AS 'C2', C3 AS 'C3')
        );
```

Still you have to specify the column names as a list. If you want a fully dynamic query, You should try doing this at the presentation layer instead of database layer.

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c483c69255de2511d179673ae8c7cc38)

Answer (score 0):

One straightforward approach uses a union query:

```sql
SELECT ID, 'C1' AS Category, C1 AS Category_Value FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, 'C2', C2 FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, 'C3', C3 FROM yourTable
ORDER BY ID, Category;
```

Comment: You are right, but I will add that I need It dynamic, because today I have 40 columns next week I can have 50 columns - I added this remark to the post